# OCR with pytesseract

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I'm trying to use OCR in order to read numbers from the given picture.

This is my original picture:
https://prnt.sc/u42wn3

I've tried to change the picture for both options:

- https://prnt.sc/u42x2l
- https://prnt.sc/u42xku

and I'm running the next code:

```
img = Image.open(r"C:\Users\peleg\Desktop\screenshots\hp_black.png")  # read the black on white picture
new_img = img.resize((80 * 2, 15 * 3)) # resizing the picture
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(new_img,config='-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789/') # exporting text from image
print(data)
```

I've tried multiple sizes and still I don't receive anything.

Comment: please ensure you have pytesseract cmd installed if you are on windows

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out if you have the appropriate OEM and PSM, which you can learn more about [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/tesseract.1.asc) (--psm and --oem sections)

You can specify an oem or psm mode as specified in the [pytesseract documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) as follows:

> ## Example of adding any additional options.

```
custom_oem_psm_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6'
pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config=custom_oem_psm_config)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second image should work. But I @achraf is probably right: you should supply a psm. Even the most basic psm (6) seems to work on this image. Your scaling is off. the original is 237x86. And you're scaling it to 160x45. I would recommend leaving the width and height parameters as 0 and supplying fx and fy scale factors

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('original.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  

thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
thresh = cv2.resize(thresh, (0,0), fx=2, fy=2)  # scale image 2X

detected_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh)
print(detected_text)
```